# Dependend Constraint in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I have not much experience with MySQL or SQL in general, and I don't want to dive into it too deeply. But I just wanna ask this:

I've got two columns, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(parent INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL, ordering INT);
```

I just want a constraint that makes sure that if the `parent` key is the same, the `ordering` must be different. Or in maths:

```
For all f1,f2 in foo: parent(f1) = parent(f2) => ordering(f1) =/= ordering(f2)
```

How can I express that in MySQL?

Comment: If you don't want to dive into it too deeply, one would have to assume that you don't care to understand an answer provided here.  Then, why should we care to provide an answer?

Comment: Hm, I agree. It's just I dislike touching the SQL directly, that's why I said I don't want to get into it too deeply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `=/=` means "not equal" (which would be `!=` or `<>` in SQL terminology).

A unique index on (parent, ordering) should do that:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_order_unique ON foo (parent, ordering);
```